# How to install any software on windows os using command prompt ONLY?

Tags: windows, cmd, installation, operating-system, command-prompt

I have to install software(.exe/.msi) on Windows OS with command prompt just like it is done on Linux. Are there any commands available for this ? Have anyone tried this before ? What I am expecting is Linux like installation i.e., with commands only. I don't want any GUI to appear on screen except a command prompt window. I've to install software silently on Windows OS.

I followed one article but it suggested me to go to the directory where (.exe/.msi) exists and type name of that exe and hit enter. But by this step, normal GUI windows appear just like we do by double clicking on exe and we just click on "next" until it is finished. I don't expect this behaviour.

I want everything to be taken care by command prompt only. I am not even aware whether this is even possible in windows or not. If anyone has tried this and succeeded, kindly share commands step by step. If you know any books or articles that I should go through, kindly suggest.

Comment: Are you talking about a specific .exe, or you're question is general?

Comment: Is it okay to install the program in an automated non-silent way?

Comment: @moeassal I'm not talking about any specific .exe but it's a general question. I have to install it silently with command prompt. By the way, what method of automated installation in non-silent way are you talking about ?

Comment: Try using `installer.exe /silent /install`.

Comment: If its an `msi` file you can use `msiexec.exe /package filename.msi /quiet`

Comment: You can use full powershell for the full installation. See https://github.com/NicoNekoru/Windows-Setup-Tools/blob/master/Auto%20Install%20Stuff

Comment: @NekoMusume Thanks for your reply. I tried **installer.exe /silent /install** but it launched installation UI window as we normally do on Windows OS. I was going through articles, I came to know that it also depends on using which systems/package that installation.exe is made. I'm not sure whether that's true. Please suggest.

Comment: It is true but the `/silent` switch is on most... Try using `installer.exe /?` to see commands.

Answer (score 1):

You will have to read the product documentation that you are installing.  It depends if the program has command line parameters to cater for all the GUI questions.

Try running the program from the command prompt with /? after the program_name.exe .
eg. program_name.exe /?

If the developer included command line options you might be lucky to find some help there, but read the product documentation as your starting point.

It's Windows, not Linux, do not expect to find may apps with command line parameters.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I'll try that command after going through the product documentation.

Answer (score 0):

To install software from CMD:

1. Launch CMD.
2. In terminal execute `start your-exe-name.exe`
3. You'll get GUI prompt then keep proceeding. Bingo, software is installed!!!

In case you get error related to Admin rights. Better to launch CMD as administrator.